# Automatically cut out sections of a video delineated by a sound.

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation, automation

Is there any way that I can automatically cut a video based on a sound.

I have a couple of long sections of video that contain videos.  I would like to remove the parts of the video that do not fall between two whistles, much like football game footage.

The video format is `mp4`.  I am looking for some type of software that would allow me to do this.

I have not had any luck with automatic video spliters because they will only split based on file size. Currently, I am cutting this footage by hand using iMovie.

Comment: So something that will look for waveform spikes? Or a certain frequency? I do not know how you would aquire this, especially not if it needs to be automated. Not unless the sounds are distinct and no other recorded audio is very similar?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this myself, but I think it's quite doable.

First, you'd need to setup a ffmpeg script to demux the video into audio and video portions. Then, you'd need to apply a script that will analyze the audio file. Silence is easier to automatically detect in an audio file, assuming that you can produce the silence on site to mark the intervals (e.g. disconnect the mic for 2 seconds). You'd need to know some programming, but with something like Python it would be quite easy.

Finally, with the output of the script as times to cut between, feed this into ffmpeg again on the original file, using the -ss  -t  command.

Answer (score 0):

if you have After Effects, there is a script for that.  You essentially import your footage into AE, and then run the script.  Here is a [link for more information](http://aescripts.com/magnum-the-edit-detector/):

> Automatically detects edits in footage. To use it you simply select a
>   footage layer in a comp, set the work area to the region you'd like to
>   find edits and tell Magnum to go to work!

Comment: I don't see how this software uses the audio to detect scenes. Is that a feature that is not shown in the video?